# Make list of indexed keywords for each section

Tags: indexing, subdividing

I made an index in my document with the makeidx package and `\index{}` command. Now I would like to summarize all indiced entries in front of each section (in form of a set of the keywords inside brackets and without page numbers) which are used in the section. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
% Display here all indexes used in Section 1
\index{First index}
\index{Second index}

\section{Section 2}
% Display here all indexes used in Section 2
\index{Third index}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a preliminary version, using `imakeidx` and its multiple-index-feature.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}%
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtotcounter{totalsections}
\newcounter{loopcounter}

\makeindex[name=indexsec1,title={Index of section 1}]
\makeindex[name=indexsec2,title={Index of section 2}]

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
% Display here all indexes used in Section 1
\index[indexsec\number\value{totalsections}]{First index}


\index[indexsec\number\value{totalsections}]{Second index}

\printindex[indexsec\number\value{totalsections}]

\section{Section 2}
% Display here all indexes used in Section 2
\index[indexsec\number\value{totalsections}]{Third index}

\printindex[indexsec\number\value{totalsections}]



\end{document}
```

### Improved version with automatic usage of `index[indexsec#]`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{assoccnt}%
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{totalsections}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{section}{totalsections}%

\newcounter{loopcounter}

\newcommand{\indexsecname}{indexsec}

\newcommand{\sectionindexprefix}[1]{%
\indexsecname\number\value{#1}%
}%


\newcounter{maxindexsections}
\setcounter{maxindexsections}{10}


\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} <  \numexpr\value{maxindexsections}+1}{%
  \makeindex[name=\sectionindexprefix{loopcounter}]
}%



\let\indexoriginal\index

\renewcommand{\index}[2][\sectionindexprefix{totalsections}]{%
  \indexoriginal[#1]{#2}
}%


\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{totalsections}}{0}{\IfFileExists{\sectionindexprefix{totalsections}.idx}{\printindex[\sectionindexprefix{totalsections}]}{}}{}%
%  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{numberofsections}{\number\totvalue{totalsections}}}
}%

\xpretocmd{\@sect}{\ifnumgreater{\value{totalsections}}{0}{\IfFileExists{\sectionindexprefix{totalsections}.idx}{\printindex[\sectionindexprefix{totalsections}]}{}}{}}{}{}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
% Display here all indexes used in Section 1
\blindtext[10]

\index{First index}


\index{Second index}

\index{Intermediate index of first section}


\section{Section 2}
% Display here all indexes used in Section 2
\index{Third index}

\section{Section 3}
\blindtext[10]
\index{Fourth index}



\end{document}
```

Comment: In the first example i had to add `\makeindex` to run it properly, but then it worked when producing a "miniindex" at the end of the section. Is it possible to do this right after the section title and more just listening the keywords in a row (no need for page numbers)? 
I.e. output: 
Section 2
(MV frontier, correlation, tangency portfolio)

Comment: @SebastianBüchler: You are asking another question not contained in your OP. In principle, my initial solution should work, if `shell-escape` is enabled, no additional need to use `\makeindex`

Comment: Actually the positioning part is visible in the MWE (display before any definition of indexes). The other part regarding how it should be displayed was just not specified enough by 'summarize all entries'.

Comment: @SebastianBüchler: You edited the post away from the initial question, such that my solution is effectively useless

Comment: @ChristanHupfer: This is not true, I precised it due to confusion. You interpreted it just the way you wanted it and now you're stubborn on that. I think we are on the right way, but need further development on the answer.

Comment: @SebastianBüchler: I can change the appearance of the index right after the section starts, but you know that I can see (as any other user here) that you added text to your question) some time **after** I posted my 'solution', requesting further stuff. Deshalb bin ich widerspenstig wie ein Esel, weil die Seite nicht so konzipiert ist ;-)

Comment: I know that edits are visible for everyone and it just supports what I said about precising the question. Obviously it was not precise enough for you, therefore I added the additional description to get rid of the confusion. However the question remains the same and is still unsolved.

Comment: Take a look on the `glossaries` package by N. Talbot... it's of more use than `\printindex` as it closes the index file as soon it appears, so the index can be not directly printed without much ado.